# get average value "30" of 2 random number

Tags: java, random, for-loop, while-loop, average

I am trying to get average of 2 random number. the average should 30 and the first number should be less than the second number. However, I'm stuck in the loop function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String respond;
    System.out.println("enter OK");
    respond = user_input.next();
    randomAverage();

}

public static void randomAverage(){
    Random random = new Random();
    int average = 30;
    int a = random.nextInt(100); //random range
    int b = random.nextInt(100);
    System.out.println("random a " +a);
    System.out.println("random b "+b);
    while(a>b){
        a = random.nextInt(100); //random range
        b = random.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println("random a " +a);
        System.out.println("random b "+b);
    }
    int c = (a+b)/2;
    while (c>average || c<average){
        a = random.nextInt(100); //random range
        b = random.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println("random a " +a);
        System.out.println("random b "+b);
    }
}
```

I tried the above function, however I got redundant data

anyone can help me

I'm just started to learn this language

Comment: You are aware that if your first random number pick is 30, you'll have redundant data anyway? Since you pick two random numbers the other will have to be 30 as well.

Comment: apply `while((a+b)==30)` and iterate your loop

Comment: if you want the average to always be exactly 30, then only the 1st number can be truly random. the 2nd number would always need to be (60-{1st number})

Comment: What do you mean by redundant data?  What exactly are you expecting to be output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never updating the value of `c`.

Your second loop should look something like:

```
int c = (a+b)/2;
while (c != average) {              // Simpler conditional
    a = random.nextInt(100);
    b = random.nextInt(100);
    c = (a+b)/2;                    // Must update this.
    System.out.println("random a " +a);
    System.out.println("random b "+b);
}
```

Note as [radai mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168951/get-average-value-30-of-2-random-number#comment19631982_14168951),

Since `(a+b)/2 = 30`, if you know `a` you can solve for `b`. No sense burning CPU cycles when simply `b = 60 - a`.

Comment: @Note what @radai said though. This program is somewhat pointless. You can **always** calculate `b` from a random `a`.  `(a+b)/2 = 30` Given `a = A`, solve for `b`.

Comment: Using a loop and a random range up to 99 is overkill see my answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey did you read my answer? I state at the end that it is overkill. I was merely fixing the problem he had in the first place.

Comment: You could note that the random range should be [0, 30] and give a solution.

Comment: @PeterLawrey true. Although, I'm tired ATM, so I instead upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop as the second value is determined by the first.  The range of the smallest value is 0 to 30 and the range of the second value is 30 to 60.

```
int first = rand.nextInt(31);
int second = 60 - first;
```

This will give you two values with an average of 30 where the first is lower.

Answer (score 0):

Use `do-while` loop as below:

```
    do{
         a = random.nextInt(100);
         b = random.nextInt(100);
         c = (a+b)/2; 
    }while(c != 30 || a >=b);
    System.out.println("random a " +a);
    System.out.println("random b "+b);
```

Please be aware the `c` is not being calculated right as it omits the fraction e.g. if a = 25 and b = 36, c will be 30 though actual average is 30.5.

**EDIT:** Best solution could be to derive one random number and just derive the second one without any loop as below:

```
    a = random.nextInt(60);
    b = 60 - a;
    System.out.println("random a " +a);
    System.out.println("random b "+b);
```

Since first number is random, second is derived random :)